# for loop doesn't work as I expected

Tags: javascript

The for loop just return me 0 as cantidad value, I supposed it should have returned 2 due facturas has 2x pagado. Ty

```
facturas=["Mario:pagado","Vane:pagado","Velez:deuda"];

function extractNames(string){
  end=string.indexOf(":");
  return string.slice(0,end);
}

function countPaids(texto){
  count=0;
  start=texto.indexOf(":")+1;
  if(texto.slice(start,texto.length)=="pagado"){
    count++;}
    return {cantidad:count};
}

for(i=0;i<facturas.length;i++){
  factura=facturas[i];
  for(factura=0;factura<facturas.length;factura++){
    countPaids(facturas[factura]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Remember to declare your variables with `var`.

Comment: `countPaids(facturas[factura]);` --- so you call a function. Then what? Result of this execution isn't saved anywhere

Comment: you say factura = facturas[i] then immediately redefine that to 0 in your for loop

Comment: `factura=facturas[i];` - you initialize a variable with some value, then `factura=0` you overwrite it with `0` on a next line.

Comment: I pretended use as argument in countPaids the own facturas[factura],so it should return as cantidad 2?

Comment: thank you so much and I apologize if this question is not in the relevant topic

Answer (score 2):

Given that the other answer already solves your particular issue, I would provide some input on how to improve your code:

You forgot to declare all your variables. When you omit the `var` keyword, your variables become implicit globals; you don't want this.

I would suggest rethinking your data structure. In JavaScript we have arrays and objects. A common way to store information is in collections, which are simply arrays of objects. This will improve readability of your code, and you can easily loop collections with native JavaScript methods and your own helpers. For example:

```
// A collection
var facturas = [
  {name: 'Mario', state: 'pagado'},
  {name: 'Vane', state: 'pagado'},
  {name: 'Velez', state: 'deuda'}
];

// Helpers to work with collections
var dot = function(s) {
  return function(x) {
    return x[s];
  };
};

var eq = function(s) {
  return function(x) {
    return x == s;
  };
};

// Example
var states = facturas.map(dot('state')); //=> ['pagado','pagado','deuda']
var totalPaid = states.filter(eq('pagado')).length; //=> 2
```

Comment: +1 for the collection suggestion although I think introducing him to higher order functions like that might be too much. Then again, I'd use a reduce here probably with this datastructure, so I'm just as bad if not worse in that regard :D

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a function which resets count to `0` every time. Do your counting in your loop instead:

```
var facturas = ["Mario:pagado","Vane:pagado","Velez:deuda"];

function extractNames(string){
    var end = string.indexOf(":");
    return string.slice(0, end);
}

/* returns true if the string contains "pagado" after the ":" */
function isPaid(texto){
    var start = texto.indexOf(":") + 1;
    return texto.slice(start,texto.length) == "pagado";
}

var count = 0;
for(var factura = 0; factura < facturas.length; factura++){
    count += isPaid(facturas[factura]);
}

// count == 2 here.
```

Don't forget to declare all your variables within the function scope you want to use them by using the `var` keyword.

Comment: What is the purpose of the outer loop?

Comment: @zerkms I thought that was a function definition. Shows how little I'm paying attention. I removed the extra loop.

Comment: `var count = ["Mario:pagado","Vane:pagado","Velez:deuda"].filter(function(f){ return f.split(":").pop() === "pagado"}).length;`